CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
I'm learning CMake and got stuck at the first step. I ensured I have make and cmake already installed, I used it in my company projects.
Now tutorial asked to do a cmake .. in the build folder with an empty CMakeLists.txt
And I get this error :
    CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
  code such as

    project(ProjectName)

  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Running

   'D:/path/ninja' '--version'

  failed with:

   %1 is not a valid Win32 application


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

So my first question is how to resolve this?
Then I checked the CMakeCache.txt that got generated and found this :
//Program used to build from build.ninja files.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=D:/path/ninja

My second question is :
I'm not sure if I'm even asking the right question or not but isn't ninja a different build system altogether?
What I understood is cmake is used to generate make build system files. Ninja is another build system like make. What is cmake doing with this build.nanja ?

Well, since you didn't show us the command you used to invoke cmake there's not much specific we can say, except that the cmake -G option is used to choose the generator (make, ninja, visual studio, etc.) and it appears you're using the wrong one, or cmake is choosing the wrong default.  Check the cmake manual for how to use -G.

"Now tutorial asked to do a cmake .. in the build folder with an empty CMakeLists.txt" - I wonder, which tutorial suggests to use empty CMakeLists.txt? I mean, put away that tutorial and choose another one.

@Tsyvarev it was done to check if the environment is set correctly and I would say it was a good step before starting to write commands in CMakeLists.txt
If everything was set correctly, I would have got 2 files CMakeCache.txt and Makefile

@MadScientist thanks. This seems to be the option I was looking for. My make is located in folder C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin so my first guess was to use "MinGW Makefiles" but that did not work. Got an error : CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles"
I tried "MSYS Makefiles" and it looks like it worked but faced another error :
`  The C compiler
"C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"

is not able to compile a simple test program.`

@MadScientist This is the error, which file is it not able to locate?
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh.exe -c "/D/cmakeSetup/cmake-3.30.4-windows-x86_64/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --progress-dir=/D/Udemy Courses/Master_CMake_for_Cross-Platform_C++_Project_Building_update_06Dec2020/m2l2_Build_Files_Generation_Process/my_build_dir/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-lhnsmw/CMakeFiles --progress-num=1 Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a0800.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj", ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

The error message %1 is not a valid Win32 application is about inability to run 'D:/path/ninja' '--version'. Have you tried the same command from the command line? This would be the first step to debug the problem.

It's looking for sh.exe (the first command in the result).
